# Что происходит когда я создаю Обработчик событий

Tags: javascript

Что именно происходит когда я создаю addEventListener? В браузере создается одно новое демон приложение, которое следит только за одной вещью которую мы ему задали, или как вообще? 
+ Если я создаю много обработчиков влияет ли это на производительность?

Я просто думаю, что по сути нет разницы сколько их создано - Javascript сам будет фильтровать их у себя внутри и выбирать реагировать только на нужные события. Я прав или нет.

Надеюсь донес мысль.

Comment: [спецификация](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-eventtarget-addeventlistener)

Comment: Ивент ждет определенного действия, и потом срабатывает, когда действие совешенно - вызывается функция.

Comment: наглядная демонстрация общего принципа, как браузер исполняет js : http://latentflip.com/loupe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Что именно происходит когда я создаю `addEventListener`?

**Версия очень упрошенная и может отличаться от того, как оно сделано в браузере!**

У каждого элемента DOM есть список событий.
Список событий o это объект у которого свойства - ("название события" : [события]).

Часть событий, это стандартные события элемента

**Пример:** hover для ссылки, ссылка меняет цвет.

**Пример списка событий:**

```
{
    "prop1": 1,
    "prop2": 2,
    "events":  {
        "onClick": [
            function (eventObject) {...},
            function (eventObject) {...},
            function (eventObject) {...}
            ...
        ]
        "onChange": [
            function (eventObject) {...},
            function (eventObject) {...},
            function (eventObject) {...}
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

После действия пользователя срабатывает определенное событие для данного обекта, например `onChange`:

```
obj.trigger("onChange", eventObject);
```

`eventObject` обект содержащий информацию о событии(Может быть что угодно).

После чего парралелно или последовательно(здесь зависит от исполнения) вызываются все функции списка `onChange`.
Цепочку событий можно прервать

```
eventObject.preventDefault();
```

Приблезительно так.

### Если я создаю много обработчиков влияет ли это на производительность?

Влияет. Больше событий, дольше исполнять. Но не сильно, думаю производители браузеров это давно оптимизировали.